# Creating a link to a page that is dynamically loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let's say you have a page like facebook.
You have a certain group page or a company page that has navigation links such as: `Information`, `Events`, `Photos`.

I would like to create a standard layout which has a left navigation and a right content holder. By clicking on any of the three left navigation buttons the content on the right is fetched via jquery. The default page loaded would always be `information`.

However, what would I do when I want to link to this group, but open the `photos` page first? And if I have many of these groups, what would be the most effective way of doing this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking for, you could do this with the hash portion of the URL (the part after the # character).  Your URLs would be `http://example.com/somepage#Information`, `http://example.com/somepage#Events` and `http://example.com/somepage#Photos`.  When the browser requests one of these, the hash portion isn't sent to the server; it has to be handled at the client with code to look for a hash and take action on it.

It sounds like your page will already have client script on the navigation links to open up the information, photos, or events in a dialog or lightbox when those links are clicked.  So after wiring that up, look at the hash portion.  If it corresponds to #Photos, auto-open the photos lightbox, and so forth.

This has the advantage of being bookmarkable and shareable.  I recently did this on a page with multiple videos.  jQuery finds all the links that correspond to videos (using a class name), and turns them into video-dialog openers.  When there's a hash on the URL that corresponds to a video, I open the dialog up automatically.  Each video can be individually shared on social networking sites.